# Cumulative income by decile

Tags: data-request, economics

I was wondering if anyone knows of a data source to get national-level cumulative income accruing to each decile data for different countries.
The data used to be available on Povcalnet but I can't find it there anymore.

Comment: Branko Milanovic does research on global inequality and recently posted results by percentiles of global income level. You can look if he published the dataset or make a personal request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wrong it's actually still freely available on Povcalnet.

http://iresearch.worldbank.org/PovcalNet

Answer (score 2):

[Eurostat](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/income-and-living-conditions/data/database) has data for the member states of the European Union as well as for some other countries.

[ilc_iw01 - Distribution of income by quantiles](http://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/show.do?query=BOOKMARK_DS-050270_QID_C4A9338_UID_-3F171EB0&layout=QUANTILE,L,X,0;GEO,L,Y,0;TIME,C,Z,0;INDIC_IL,L,Z,1;CURRENCY,L,Z,2;INDICATORS,C,Z,3;&zSelection=DS-050270INDIC_IL,SHARE;DS-050270CURRENCY,EUR;DS-050270INDICATORS,OBS_FLAG;DS-050270TIME,2013;&rankName1=INDIC-IL_1_2_-1_2&rankName2=CURRENCY_1_2_-1_2&rankName3=INDICATORS_1_2_-1_2&rankName4=TIME_1_0_0_0&rankName5=QUANTILE_1_2_0_0&rankName6=GEO_1_2_0_1&rStp=&cStp=&rDCh=&cDCh=&rDM=true&cDM=true&footnes=false&empty=false&wai=false&time_mode=NONE&time_most_recent=false&lang=EN&cfo=%23%23%23%2C%23%23%23.%23%23%23)

If you are eligible you can also apply for an acceess to the data from the [Luxembourg Income Study](http://www.lisdatacenter.org). It has a wider geographical coverage: